# What does it mean when Google anti-virus engine reports "Detected"?

Tags: malware, windows, virus, antivirus

I need to convert a ton of directories of JPEGs into PDFs or EPUBs.

So I downloaded this: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/josch/img2pdf/build/artifacts

Being scared that it might be malware, as any EXE can be, I uploaded it to VirusTotal. It gave this result: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/cb85a4ce88ee138bc5895d70344edc279064d7cfd3acca7627f6fce7fbbc4e24/detection

So... Is this malware or not? Why do some engines think so? In particular, why does "Google" (?) think it's "Detected"? What does "Detected" mean?

The little "(!)" icon does not give any further information when hovered.

Comment: Hard to say, if you want 100% to be sure you need to reverse it. I'd say it's a false positive due to the different types of threats detected and because the main AVs don't detect it.

Comment: If you are worried download it from [github.com/josch/img2pdf](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf)